# How to create a custom tag field that support auto suggestion and multi value in Magnolia CMS?

Tags: java, magnolia

I want to add a tag input field that working like the tags input field on stackoverflow in Magnolia. It will support auto suggestion from existing tags, can select multi tags value and will add new tag if not existed. But I can't find any documentation on Magnolia Wiki to implement that. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are looking for content tagging feature of Magnolia. It should be enough to just enable it for your app, assuming you are using 5.6 or later version. Or if this is not what you are looking for, you can use it as inspiration to develop your own kind of tagging.

[Documentation link](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/How+to+enable+content+tags+for+a+content+app)